# Get data from a Dynamic Bean (DynaBean class)

Tags: java, dynamic, javabeans

I have a DynaBean generated from a ResultSet

```
RowSetDynaClass resultBeans = new RowSetDynaClass(result, false);
List<DynaBean> list = resultBeans.getRows();
```

I want to simple retrieve a value of my resultset from one DynaBean in Java, not in JSP page.
How can i do that?
I'm trying this:

```
DynaBean b = list.get(0);
String value = b.get("valor");
```

But i get exceptions... What should i put on b.get(????)
My resultSet is returnig 2 columns: "nome", "valor"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working with:
Clob clob = (Clob) dados.get("valor");

I found out that my query is returning a Clob object.